# PowerShell RegEx: get SID from string

Tags: regex, powershell

I am trying to run a powershell command to return a SID from a string.

```
$string = "The SID is S-1-9-1551374245-3853148685-361627209-2951783729-4075502353-0-0-0-0-3"

Select-String -Pattern "\bS-\d{1}-\d{1}-\d{10}-\d{10}-\d{9}-\d{10}-\d{10}-\d{1}-\d{1}-\d{1}-\d{1}-\d{1}\b" -InputObject $string
```

when I run the above, it returns the whole string but I only want the SID # which is 'S-1-9-1551374245-3853148685-361627209-2951783729-4075502353-0-0-0-0-3'

Comment: `$res = [regex]::match($string,'\bS-\d-\d(?:-\d{10}){2}-\d{9}(?:-\d{10}){2}(?:-\d){5}\b').Value`

Comment: your problem is that you are using `Select-String` that `gasp! arg!` **_selects strings_**. [*grin*] either pull the match out of the `MatchInfo` object OR  use normal regex with `-match` and get the value from the `$Matches` automatic variable.

Comment: taking a slightly different approach ... is the sample data you posted accurate? if it is, then you can simply use `.Split(' ')` and select the last item in the resulting array.

Comment: Where did you get the string from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$Pattern = 'S-\d-(?:\d+-){1,14}\d+'
$Matches =  Select-String -Pattern $Pattern -InputObject $string
if ( $Matches ) { $Matches.Matches.Value }
```

Credit for [*vs97*'s regex pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58036131/3439404)

Answer (score 4):

You can try the following regex:

```
S-\d-(?:\d+-){1,14}\d+
```

[Regex Demo](https://regexr.com/4ldj8)

Explanation:

```
S-              # Match S- literally
\d-             # Match a digit- literally
(?:\d+-){1,14}  # Non-capturing group to match recursively digit- from 1-14 times
\d+             # Match digit recursively
```

Answer (score 1):

As shown in [JosefZ's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58036196/45375), your only problem was that you didn't extract the match of interest from the properties of the [`[Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.powershell.commands.matchinfo) object that your `Select-String` call outputs.

However, using a cmdlet is a bit heavy-handed in this case; the [`-replace` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375) offers a simpler and better-performing alternative:

```
$string = "The SID is S-1-9-1551374245-3853148685-361627209-2951783729-4075502353-0-0-0-0-3"

$string -replace `
  '.*\b(S-\d-\d-\d{10}-\d{10}-\d{9}-\d{10}-\d{10}-\d-\d-\d-\d-\d)\b.*', 
  '$1'
```

<sup>I've simplified your regex a bit: `\d{1}` -> `\d`. Note that it doesn't match all possible forms that SIDs can have.</sup>

Note how the regex matches the *entire* input string, and replaces it with just the what the capture group (`(...)`, the subexpression matching the SID) matched (`$1`).

Answer (score 0):

Your expression seems to be just fine, maybe a bit modification,

```
\bS(?:-\d){2}(?:-\d{10}){2}-\d{9}(?:-\d{10}){2}(?:-\d){5}\b
```

would be OK, other than that it should have worked though.

#### [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/K5pacy/1/)

Or with a lookbehind:

```
(?<=The SID is )\S+
```

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/74rGxg/1/)